# Change the margin twice on one page

Tags: margins, multicol, report

I am attempting to change the margin on a section of the first page of my report.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=25.4mm, right=25.4mm, top=12.7mm, bottom=25.4mm]{geometry}


%\setlength\parindent{12pt} % Indentation

\begin{document}
\newgeometry{left=12.7mm, right=12.7mm, top=12.7mm, bottom=25.4mm}
\begin{flushright}
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{flushright}
   \includegraphics[width=3in]{Some-place.jpg} 
   \end{flushright}
\end{figure}
\large A conference title
\end{flushright}
\begin{centering}
\LARGE {A generic title}\\[0.5cm]
\large \textsc{The author\\
\small \textit{The author's address}\\[0.75cm]
\end{centering}
\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}
\end{minipage}

\begin{multicols*}{2}

\section*{ABSTRACT}
Exciting text to sell the abstract!
```

This is the code  I am using which works except the abstract begins on the next page with a load of white space after the title. Is there any way to get the title to be full page with 1.27cm left and right margins then the 2 columns start immediately after with 2.54cm margins? Thanks.

Comment: It's not really clear what you want to obtain. But the code is not compilable; please, make it into a working example. And remove the `figure` environment around `\includegraphics`: it's wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a document header that's wider than the normal text width, it's simpler to use a box; you can't change the page geometry inside a page. Note that `figure` is unnecessary.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=25.4mm, right=25.4mm, top=12.7mm, bottom=25.4mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % demo is just for the example
\usepackage{multicol,calc}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\begin{document}
\noindent\makebox[\textwidth][c]{%
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth+1in}
  \raggedleft
  \includegraphics[width=3in]{Some-logo.jpg}\\
  \large A conference title

  \centering
  \LARGE A generic title\\[0.5cm]
  \large \textsc{The author}\\
  \small \textit{The author's address}

  \vspace{0.2in}
  \noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}

  \vspace{0.2in}
  \end{minipage}}% this brace closes \makebox

\begin{multicols}{2}

\section*{ABSTRACT}
Exciting text to sell the abstract!

\section{Whatever}

\lipsum

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```